# main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists

Tags: magento-2.1, error, exception

When i try to access my magento after installing my custom module i got this error:

```
[2017-01-06 04:37:41] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists. in C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:406
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(582): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->addItem(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor))
#1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(557): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
#2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php(820): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
#3 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(78): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#4 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(58): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig()
#5 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('')
#6 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('')
#7 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get()
#8 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#9 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#10 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#11 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#12 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#13 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#14 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#15 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\pub\errors\report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#16 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(324): require('C:\\xampp7\\htdoc...')
#17 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#18 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#19 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#20 {main} [] []
[2017-01-06 04:41:43] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists. in C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:406
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(582): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->addItem(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor))
#1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(557): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
#2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php(820): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
#3 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(78): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#4 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(58): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig()
#5 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('')
#6 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('')
#7 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get()
#8 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#9 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#10 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#11 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#12 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#13 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#14 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#15 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\pub\errors\report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#16 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(324): require('C:\\xampp7\\htdoc...')
#17 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#18 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#19 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#20 {main} [] []
[2017-01-06 04:41:46] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists. in C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:406
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(582): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->addItem(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor))
#1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(557): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
#2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php(820): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
#3 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(78): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#4 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(58): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig()
#5 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('')
#6 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('')
#7 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get()
#8 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#9 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#10 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#11 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#12 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#13 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#14 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#15 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\pub\errors\report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#16 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(324): require('C:\\xampp7\\htdoc...')
#17 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#18 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#19 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#20 {main} [] []
[2017-01-06 04:43:37] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists. in C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:406
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(582): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->addItem(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor))
#1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(557): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
#2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php(820): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
#3 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(78): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#4 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(58): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig()
#5 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('')
#6 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('')
#7 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get()
#8 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#9 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#10 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#11 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#12 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#13 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#14 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#15 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\pub\errors\report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#16 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(324): require('C:\\xampp7\\htdoc...')
#17 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#18 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#19 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#20 {main} [] []
[2017-01-06 04:43:38] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists. in C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:406
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(582): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->addItem(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor))
#1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(557): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
#2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php(820): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
#3 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(78): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#4 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(58): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig()
#5 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('')
#6 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('')
#7 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get()
#8 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#9 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#10 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#11 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#12 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#13 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#14 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#15 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\pub\errors\report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#16 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(324): require('C:\\xampp7\\htdoc...')
#17 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#18 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#19 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#20 {main} [] []
[2017-01-06 04:43:41] main.CRITICAL: Exception: Item (Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor) with the same ID "0" already exists. in C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php:406
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(582): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->addItem(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value\Interceptor))
#1 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(557): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->loadWithFilter(false, false)
#2 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection.php(820): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->load()
#3 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(78): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection->getIterator()
#4 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource.php(58): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->loadConfig()
#5 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated.php(40): Magento\Config\App\Config\Source\RuntimeConfigSource->get('')
#6 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated->get('')
#7 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-config\App\Config\Type\System.php(98): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ConfigSourceAggregated\Proxy->get()
#8 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(139): Magento\Config\App\Config\Type\System->get('default/web/sec...')
#9 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(90): Magento\Framework\App\Config->get('system', 'default/web/sec...')
#10 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(103): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL)
#11 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...')
#12 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply()
#13 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#14 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array)
#15 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\pub\errors\report.php(15): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse()
#16 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(324): require('C:\\xampp7\\htdoc...')
#17 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(160): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleGenericReport(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#18 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Exception))
#19 C:\xampp7\htdocs\mage2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#20 {main} [] []
```

Comment: Remove var folder and run compile command php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 0):

Check your install schema, Your table primary key (ID) is auto incremented or not. Make ID as primary key and auto incremented.